# Toolbar, SwipeRefreshLayout and DrawerLayout

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I want to create a layout with a custom toolbar on top and a left drawer with a main content that is refresh when you pull it down. 
I've tried just about every combination, but I can't quite figure it out. What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- OUR CUSTOM TOOLBAR -->
  <!-- app:theme determines textcolor on toolbar-->
  <!-- app:popupTheme sets theme for the pop-up button on the right-->
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

  <FrameLayout android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_width="match_parent">

  <!-- REFRESH LAYOUT FOR WHEN THE USER PULLS DOWN -->
  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
      android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <TextView
          android:text="Pull to refresh"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"

          />
    </ScrollView>
  </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


  <!-- DRAWER LAYOUT -->
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- THE MAIN CONTENT VIEW -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:background="#F44248">
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="This is text inside Main content view"

          />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- THE LEFT DRAWER -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#818181"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#E3F2FD" />
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code-behind:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

namespace Test
    {


        [Activity(Label = "Test", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme ="@style/MyTheme")]
        public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
        {
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar gToolbar;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);

                // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Scroll);

            // Our custom toolbar
            gToolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(gToolbar);
            SupportActionBar.Title = "Menu";
        }
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

This is how it appears on my screen. So, even though I can swipe out the drawer, the SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't refresh the page. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Need to see code for what you are doing when the swipe refresh layout is pulled in order to help

Comment: @ConnorT I've added the code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

> The problems seems to be that the drawerlayout overlaps the swiperrefreshlayout, so the drawer is accessable, but the swiperefreshlayout is hidden behind the drawerlayout.

You are right about this, so if you want the `SwipeRefreshLayout` to work correctly, you will need to wrap the `DrawerLayout` with `SwipeRefreshLayout`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--THE MAIN CONTENT VIEW-->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="#F44248">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is text inside Main content view" />
            </RelativeLayout>

    <!--THE LEFT DRAWER-->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#818181"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#E3F2FD" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And you will get this:

[image]

Or if you simply want to refresh the main content of the `DrawerLayout`, you can wrap the first child element of DrawerLayout with the `SwipeRefreshlayout`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--THE MAIN CONTENT VIEW-->
      <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="#F44248">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is text inside Main content view" />
            </RelativeLayout>
      </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <!--THE LEFT DRAWER-->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#818181"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#E3F2FD" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And you will get something like this:

[image]

At last, don't forget to implement the Refresh event manually,as the controls won't get refreshed automatically:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar gToolbar;
    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Our custom toolbar
        gToolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        refreshLayout = FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.swipeLayout);
        refreshLayout.Enabled = true;
        refreshLayout.Refresh += RefreshLayout_Refresh;
        SupportActionBar.Title = "Menu";
    }

    private void RefreshLayout_Refresh(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //refresh the controls manually here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear Elvis, this helped me : "You are right about this, so if you want the SwipeRefreshLayout to work correctly, you will need to wrap the DrawerLayout with SwipeRefreshLayout"

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate() method, you need a listener for your SwipeRefreshLayout. You can learn about these [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html).

Add this code to your onCreate() method:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = new SwipeRefreshLayout(this);
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener(){
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // What you want to do when you refresh your layout.
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, my problem is how each of the items appear on the screen. I'm assuming it can be solved by rearranging some of the code inside the axml file, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: I've provided some screenshots so it's easier to see.

Comment: Add this code to your toolbar xml code to make the toolbar on the top: `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and this code to your left drawer xml code to make it on the left: `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

Comment: That didn't make any difference. The problems seems to be that the drawerlayout overlaps the swiperrefreshlayout, so the drawer is accessable, but the swiperefreshlayout is hidden behind the drawerlayout.

Comment: It looks like your frame layout isn't containing anything. Make sure the things you want in your frame layout are tabbed(4 spaces in).

Comment: That didn't do anything either.